# Can I determine how much crossover traffic there is between sections on my site?

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I have three sections on my shopping site: Men, Women, and Kids. I want to find out the proportion of visitors to /men/ who also go to /women/ or /kids/ etc. I don't care specifically about the top level pages, but rather about visitors to any page within the section.

Is this possible using Google Analytics? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is 'behaviour flow'.

We use this little feature on our site to see where visitors are landing and then see how they're progressing through the site and ultimately seeing where they drop off.

As per Google, *"The Behavior Flow report visualizes the path visitors traveled from one Page or Event to the next."*

When logged in and viewing your site data, simply click on 'Behaviour' from the left hand menu, and then select 'Behaviour Flow'.
From there you'll be able to customise the way you see data and visitor flow - you can set your start point at a particular page, a city or country, or any Google Ads.

[Google: About the Behavior Flow report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=en-GB)
[Google search for "google analytics Behaviour Flow"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google%20analytics%20Behaviour%20Flow) offering a wealth of advice and other webistes

It really is a great little tool and is good for picking up patterns and trends on high traffic sites.

**EDIT**
In the interest of fairness for other platforms, **Piwik** also has this feature, called *'Transitions'*. You can read about it on their features page, [here](http://piwik.org/docs/transitions/).
I've been using Piwik on personal sites for a number of years now - it's a great tool!