# Tracking visits for the next page visited after a landing page using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a landing page which we would like to analyse in Google Analytics. I have created a custom report which has a filter for the landing page.

How can I analyse the next page visitors visited after landing on the landing page?

Answer (score 1):

I've just answered a very similar question to this about 5 minutes ago. Have a read... [can i determine how much crossover traffic there is between sections on my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55143/can-i-determine-how-much-crossover-traffic-there-is-between-sections-on-my-site)

The principles are the same - you can use visitor flow reports to see how people are interacting with your site; where they land, where they go from landing, where they drop off etc...

Comment: Hi Alex - Thanks for replying. However, I am not really interested in behavior reports as they are not easily exportable.

Comment: I am looking to create a simple custom report with the next pages people visited when they landed.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood you question. I'll re-write my answer.